# boolean logic simplify

Tags: boolean-algebra

To prove:

$(X+Y)(X'+Z) = XZ + X'Y$

I try to simply $(X+Y)(X'+Z)$ to $XZ + X'Y + YZ$

then I have no idea how to simply further.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $YZ = (X+X^\prime)YZ = XYZ+X^\prime YZ$, then
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
XZ+X^\prime Y+YZ &=& XZ+X^\prime Y +XYZ+X^\prime YZ \\
 &=& XZ(1+Y)+X^\prime Y(1+Z) \\
 &=& XZ+X^\prime Y.
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} (X + Y)(X' + Z) & = (X+Y)X' + (X+Y)Z \\ \\ & = \underbrace{X'X}_{= 0} + X'Y + XZ + YZ \\ \\ & = X'Y + XZ + YZ \\ \\ & = X'Y + XZ + \underbrace{(X+ X')}_{= 1}YZ \\ \\ & = X'Y + XZ + XYZ + X'YZ \\ \\ & = X'Y\underbrace{(1 + Z)}_{= 1} + XZ\underbrace{(1 + Y)}_{= 1} \\ \\ &= X'Y + XZ \end{align}$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ +)